# How to generate number for elements in Swift array?

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm new to swift and I'm trying to create an array of names and print each of them with generated index number. for example this should be the console output:

```
1) Sam
2) Jim
3) Peter 
4) Anna 
5) John
```

I'm doing this now:

```
var namesArray = ["Sam", "Jim", "Peter", "Anna", "John"]

var nameCounter = 0

for names in namesArray {
    print("\(nameCounter+=1)) \(names)")
}
```

Comment: You could do `for name in namesArray { nameCounter += 1; print("\(nameCounter)) \(name)")}`

Comment: Avoid names like `nameArray`. Just call it `names`, the arrayness is implied (and generally irrelevant, anyway. If it were a `Set`, the code would work the same.). Also, `names` in your loop body is poorly named. It's a singular name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enumerated()` method on the collection to access moth `offset` ('aka' `Index`) and `element` at the same time without need for any counter:

```
for name in namesArray.enumerated() {
    print("\(name.offset + 1)) \(name.element)")
}
```

Note: get rid of that trailing `s` in `names`. It is just a single **name**.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, but is there any way to star index from 1?

Comment: In Swift, indices starts at 0, but you can print the +1 version.

Comment: Also frequently written as: `for (index, name) in namesArray.enumerated() { print("\(index + 1)) \(name)") }`

Comment: Note that this only works for full collections, not slices and such (where the index doesn't start at 0). Check out my answer for comparison

Comment: @Alexander, `enumerated()` always starts at `0`, even for a slice whose indices don't start at `0`.

Comment: @vacawama Ah nvm, I remembered it wrong. It was the opposite, enumerated acts like `zip(0..., sequence)`, which doesn't necessarily represent the indices of a collection.

Comment: @Alexander, `zip` does allow you to match up the actual indices more easily with `zip(slice.indices, slice)`.

Comment: @vacawama Yep, i remember that

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip`, in combination with an open range starting at 1:

```
let names = ["Sam", "Jim", "Peter", "Anna", "John"]

for (n, name) in zip(1..., names) {
    print("\(n)) \(name)")
}
```